# Maven fails to download dependencies and leaves always corrupt .jars behind on IntellIJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have issues using Maven lately.

I ran in THIS error:

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.spigotmc:spigot-api:jar:1.9.4-R0.1-20160603.113501-25 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.spigotmc:spigot:jar:1.9.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:jar:4.48 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-jdbc:jar:4.48 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.bukkit:bukkit:jar:1.6.4-R2.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.2.2 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for net.milkbowl.vault:VaultAPI:jar:1.5 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for code.aterstones:nickapi:jar:1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.inventivetalent:particleapi:jar:2.1.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for redis.clients:jedis:jar:2.8.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[WARNING] The POM for org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:jar:3.3.0 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
```

Maven tries to download the JARS from the dependencies, but fails and leaves an 1kb large jar (which is obviously corrupted) behind. Deleting the .m2 folder did not do a thing.

Each error of this one shows also with -X enabled the following error:

```
[ERROR] 'modelVersion' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'groupId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'artifactId' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
[ERROR] 'version' is missing. @ [unknown-group-id]:[unknown-artifact-id]:[unknown-version]
```

I tried the following:

- Reinstall Windows complete
- Using latest Maven instead of IntelliJ Bundled Maven
- Updating JRE and JDK to 8.101
- Disabling the Firewall

I am using IntelliJ Ultimate 16.2.3 on Windows 10.

Am I missing something to configure Maven? On my Surface, the project runs and compiles fine, but on my PC it does not!

Edit:

Full log : [Full Log](http://hastebin.com/uhadokoyif.scala)

POM: [POM](http://hastebin.com/oqatinilaw.xml)

**Note: The project regarding this error works on my other PC! It is just this PC which wont work!**

Comment: Please show the full log output...I assume proxy/firewall issue

Comment: Edited full log in as link

Comment: can you also provide your pom ?

Comment: @Bolzano Added the POM, although it works on the other PC.

Comment: Somehow maven can't reach the remote repositories that you've provided, I couldn't even ping  theyeticave.net, currently its offline. Did you try copying the .m2 folder's content  from another computer (which already works) to your current computer ?

Comment: yup, tried that too. Did not work either

Comment: did you get any error from it ? same error ?

Comment: Ok. This is strange. Copying .m2 now from the other pc works. But why doesnt it want to load from the repos? I mean, spigot e.g should work. But it is been marked as error in IntelliJ.

Comment: spigot works for me, only  <artifactId>spigot</artifactId> didnt work for me because it doesn't exist in their repo, you can check your .m2 folder is that really exists ? for the vault-repo i used this  <url> http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases </url> and it works also but im not sure about is this url fully official or secure .